# How to enable HSTS for Google Cloud Run app?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

My Google Cloud Run app use traditional 302 responses to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS. Is there any way to have Google Cloud Run make use of HSTS header?

My app stack is `express`. I tried `helmet.hsts()` but it's not working. It seems that HTTP requests will be redirected by Google proxy before they come to my `express` app.

Here is my sample request and response:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: <URL>
*   Trying 2001:4860:4802:36::35...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <HOST> (2001:4860:4802:36::35) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: <HOST>
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: <URL>
< X-Cloud-Trace-Context: e1f3dfe0e7bd604c447ca0c8f8c0ea5c
< Date: Thu, 24 Jun 2021 10:23:48 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Server: Google Frontend
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host <HOST> left intact
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't customize Cloud Run built-in proxy. And thus you can't add the header that you want like the strict transport security header.

However, as workaround, you can deploy a HTTPS Load Balancer and add your Cloud Run service as [Serverless NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless) backend. Then, you have to configure the [HTTPS Load Balancer to add a custom header](https://serverfault.com/a/1050590)

Comment: Hmmm are you sure? Either while editing or creating a new one, if you select a serverless backend (Cloud Run, Function etc.) the option for custom response headers is not there.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I did it, and write an article on that: https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-load-balancing-go-beyond-your-own-project-adfa1c8b001d

Comment: Found the issue, I created the LB with a Serveless NEG instead of an Internet one. I'll look into it, thanks!